# How to invoke another class when message received in android

Tags: sms

**This is my sms receiver**

```
package com.example.smsTest;


import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;



 public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";        
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(context, SMSTest.class);
        mainActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(mainActivityIntent);

        //---send a broadcast intent to update the SMS received in the activity---
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("sms", str);
        context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

    }                       
}
}
```

This is manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.smsTest"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8"
    android:maxSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".SMSTest"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="99999">
            <action android:name="android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECIEVED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
   </application>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
</uses-permission>


enter code here

</manifest>
```

I want to call the another class named as SMSText.class from above SmsReceiver class. I wrote the above but its not working.

Comment: yes, it is not starting the specified activity with intent. Just the default app of SMS Messaging is showing incoming messages

Comment: it is already in SmsReceiver class at last, if u asked for broadcastintent of activity to be invoked is:                                                                                         private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
//---display the SMS received in the TextView---
            TextView SMSes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            SMSes.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("sms")); };

Comment: I had seen one tutorial in android beginners book as they said that to    invoke the activity. So I just copied that code.

Comment: Still the above mentioned is only coming. Not starting the activity

Comment: when a message is received a notification is given and when opened it is opening in Messaging app already present in android.

Comment: yes, I had removed and only what you have said is coded.

Comment: no no it is giving notification in the top panel that is  drop down panel where battery indicator and signals are shown I think you got it?

Comment: ok fine, then how should i get it?

Comment: Thank you very much for your support Mr. Mike, I can't trace out that misspelled thing. It's working.............. :D

Comment: Suggest this is closed as "typographical error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SmsReceiver` do the following:

```
Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(context, SMSTest.class);
mainActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mainActivityIntent.putExtra("sms", str);
context.startActivity(mainActivityIntent);
```

Then, in the Activity's `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView SMSes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String sms = getIntent().getStringExtra("sms");
    SMSes.setText(sms);
}
```

You've misspelled "RECEIVED" in the `<intent-filter>` in your manifest, so your BroadcastReceiver isn't firing. It should be:

```
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String activity= "android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECIEVED";
Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(activity);
startActivity(mainActivityIntent);
```

Comment: Thanq, This also not working just showing in inbox when message received. Not starting another activity.